# SetOnMouseMoved() not working after SetOnMousePressed()

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a button when I click it runs a function. I also have a separate SetOnMouseMoved event to get information when I hover over other cells in my grid example. My SetOnMouseMoved event will not work after I have pressed the setOnMouseClicked.

```
   Button btn = new Button("Uniform Path");
   GridPane gp = new GridPane();
   gp.add(btn, 0,1)

   btn.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> (){
        @Override 
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
             SomeFunction();  
        }
    });

    // gp.getChildren() refers to StackPane grid cells in which I
    // hover over and get information from that cell.    
    for (Node index : gp.getChildren()) {
        index.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.print("Row: " + GridPane.getRowIndex(index));
                System.out.println("Column: " + GridPane.getColumnIndex(index));
            }
        });
    }

   Scene scene = new Scene(gp);
```

Comment: Why not use `setOnMouseEntered` instead of `setOnMoseMoved`?

Comment: Tried that as well, doesn't work :(

Comment: Use `setOnAction` for your button.

Comment: JavaFX uses one thread to control the application thread (UI) and all events are processed sequentially in it. When this thread is blocked by some logic (`SomeFunction ()`), it can not handle the other events correctly. Therefore any logic that takes time is exported into a separate thread.
Separately, you are talking about mousePressed. When pressed, javafx does not generate mouseMoved events but generates mouseDragged events.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> setOnMouseMoved: Defines a function to be called when mouse cursor moves within this Node but no buttons have been pushed.
>
> setOnMouseDragged: Defines a function to be called when a mouse button is pressed on this Node and then dragged.

You just need to implement setOnMouseDragged the same as setOnMouseMoved.